# What is vector CB expressed in terms of vectors m and n?

Tags: vector

In triangle ABC, point D is on AB, and BD is equal to 2 times DA. Let vector CA be equal to vector m, and let vector CD be equal to vector n. What is vector CB expressed in terms of vectors m and n?

The following code can only draw an image, how can it automatically calculate the results required by the question?

```
GeometricScene[{a, b, c, d}, {Triangle@{a, b, c}, 
  GeometricAssertion[{a, d, b}, "Collinear"], 
  EuclideanDistance[d, b] == 2 EuclideanDistance[a, d], 
  GeometricAssertion[{a, b}, {"OppositeSides", Line[{c, d}]}], 
  Line[{c, d}]}]
RandomInstance[%]
```

[image]

How can it automatically calculate the results required by the question?

What is vector CB expressed in terms of vectors m and n?

Answer (score 4):

Roughly speaking, construct a new point F on line CD (vector $\vec{n}$) so that line FB is parallel to CA (vector $\vec{m}$).  Then let $x$ be the distance to go from C to F (in the $\vec{n}$ direction) in units of the distance CD.  Let $y$ be distance to come back from F to B (in the negative $\vec{m}$-direction)

```
s = GeometricScene[{a, b, c, d,f}, {Triangle@{a, b, c}, 
    GeometricAssertion[{a, d, b}, "Collinear"],
    EuclideanDistance[d, b] == 2 EuclideanDistance[a, d],  
    GeometricAssertion[{a, b}, {"OppositeSides", Line[{c, d}]}], 
    Line[{c, d}],
    GeometricAssertion[{c, d, f}, "Collinear"],  
    GeometricAssertion[{c, f}, {"OppositeSides", Line[{a,b}]}],
    GeometricAssertion[{Line[{f,b}],Line[{c,a}]},"Parallel"],
    Line[{f,d}]}];
r = RandomInstance[s]
```

[image]

```
{{x,y}} = GeometricSolveValues[r,
    {EuclideanDistance[c,f]/EuclideanDistance[c,d],
     EuclideanDistance[b,f]/EuclideanDistance[c,a] }]

(* {{2.99998,1.99993}} *)
```

These results indicate the answer is $3\vec{n}-2\vec{m}$.

The exact solution can be obtained by solving the geometric scene, $s$ instead of the instance $r$.

```
{{x,y}} = GeometricSolveValues[s,
    {EuclideanDistance[c,f]/EuclideanDistance[c,d],
     EuclideanDistance[b,f]/EuclideanDistance[c,a] }]

(* {{3,2}} *)
```